# Lightweight profiling for Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I would like to profile certain actions in my application in a production environment.

I have previously used [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) in .NET
It does not seem to exist in Silverlight (despite being in the documentation).

Can anyone suggest some alternatives? Is there anything better than DateTime.UtcNow?

I have used Yourkit and use ANTs in development, but I would like to gather information about performance of deployed software. I do not have access to the kind of data the users have, but can gather some logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2010/01/21/writing-a-profiler-for-silverlight-4.aspx) any use at all?

It sounds like you want to deploy profiling IN your application so you can see how it performs on the user's PC?

Comment: Correct, we don't have access to customer data, but we can collect performance stats.

Comment: It's just disappointing that silverlight does not have a good timer :(

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you could have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901021/stopwatch-for-silverlight). Standard timers (eg looking at the value of DateTime.Now) are only going to give you rough resolution, which seems to be around 16ms at best.

Otherwise you can grab a performance profiling tool, there are several now which work out of the box with Silverlight, are easy enough to use and don't really take that long to get started with, with free evaluations. Two such tools [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and [RedGate ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

Comment: Updated the question. I can't get access to the full data that the users have.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at this question: [How to profile a silverlight application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943/how-to-profile-a-silverlight-application)

Are you looking for something other than this?

Answer (score -1):

Telerik also has a pretty fantastic product for profiling named : [JustTrace](http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx)

> **JustTrace enables the profiling of local applications, running applications, Silverlight applications and local ASP .NET web site.**