# Stopwatch for Silverilght 5?

Tags: c#, silverlight, stopwatch

it doesn't have to be high resolution, but I need to find Stopwatch in System.Diagnostics in Silverlight 5. In WP7, it is in Microsoft.Phone. (Sharing code across multiple platforms.)

I think it does exist, perhaps formerly in Microsoft.Device.dll.

**Update** Temporarily, it seems work to pull the Stopwatch.cs from the Mono library (which ultimately maps Stopwatch to Timespan).

**Update2** Nope, that doesn't work, since it tries to call extern long GetTimestamp(); Probably this needs to be replaced with something SL can handle. Possibility http://blog.tiaan.com/link/2009/02/03/stopwatch-silverlight

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901021/stopwatch-for-silverlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP7, Silverlight, and WPF all have a Stopwatch in System.Diagnostics;

However, I think the problem you might be facing is sharing a library between different frameworks. In order to share libraries across multiple frameworks you need a [Announcement Portable Class Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/01/19/announcing-portable-library-tools-ctp-justin-van-patten.aspx) or [MSDN Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx)

I really recommend though you create seperate class libraries for each framework and use something like the following in code:

```
#if WPF
// using statements for WPF
#elif SILVERLIGHT
// using statements for Silverlight
#elif WP7
// using statements for WP7
#endif
```

#### EDIT

[Silverlight Stopwatch](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/723)

Comment: Do you happen to know where to find the SILVERLIGHT stopwatch library? What should I reference?

Comment: Its in System.Diagnostics http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.95%29.aspx AKA using System;

Comment: Hmm, I started a blank Silverlight 5 project and have System but it doesn't pick up.

Comment: Browsing System.dll under System.Diagnostics, there is only "Debug", no stopwatch. In WP7, found under Microsoft.Phone.dll.

Comment: It is very bad solution... since Environment.TickCount used in referenced code has less resolution than DateTime.Now.Ticks. It is 1 milliseconds in comparison to 100 nanoseconds.